# Logical architecture based on modules and SPI

Tags: java, oop, module, java-module

I'm looking for the most proper way to design a modular application with ServiceLoader.

**--MAIN IDEA--**

- module ***app.view*** | *exports* `app.view.View` interface that defines UI api
- module ***app.engine*** | *exports* `app.engine.Engine` interface that defines Engine (core functionality) api
- module ***app*** | (entry point) *requires* and *uses* `app.view`, `app.engine` in order to combine them into actual program

The app will be open for extension, anyone can add new implementations of `app.engine.Engine` and `app.view.View` interfaces.

**--CONCERNS--**

Since `app.view`, `app.engine` will be exported through *exports* keyword, it will be accessible in every other modules, also in unrelated ones. This feels like a design mistake. Is it?

On the other hand, if I'd change *exports* to *exports to* I could force it to be accessible only in related modules, but it will not be extension friendly anymore.

Is my design idea proper for that kind of application? Should I ignore my concerns? If so, why?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to let anyone add new implementations of your APIs, exporting them via unrestricted `exports` is the right choice.

> it will be accessible in every other modules, also in unrelated ones.

This is only true if the other module `requires` these API modules. Since **app** only `requires` the API, a module reading **app** does not automatically read the modules required by it. This would be different if you used `requires transitive`.

With `exports to`, you are limiting the number of modules that can provide implementations of the API to a known list. This would be similar to sealed classes; the API knows and restricts its implementations. There might be use cases for this, for example if you developed a closed system of modules and providing a service within that should be considered an implementation detail. Normally however, you want the service API to be public.